# Limit of Uniformly convegent sequence of real valued functions:

Tags: real-analysis

I was attempting this qualifying problem.
$\{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of real valued functions on $\mathbb{R}$. If $ f_n $ converges to $f$ uniformly then $f$ must be continuous.

I am little wondering about this problem . I know uniform limit of sequence of continuous functions must be continuous.

If it has to do something with 'real valued functions on $\mathbb{R}$', then I might be missing that trick , otherwise I do not see the reason that the statement is true. But I found this problem as one the past qualifying exam on the website of the university.

Anyone has some idea about this?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe every $f_n$ has to be continuous.

Comment: If that was the case , there would not be any problem. I thought the same thing at the beginning.

Comment: On the other hand, if it is not the case, there are trivial counter-examples.

Answer (score 2):

Take any discontinuous function $f$ and define the constant sequence $f_{n}=f$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Then $(f_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges uniformly to $f$, but $f$ is not continuous. So the claim must be assuming that each $f_{n}$ is continuous.

Answer (score 0):

that's wrong. Take
$$
f_n(x) = 
\begin{cases}
1, & x = 0, \\
0, & x \ne 0.
\end{cases}
$$
Then, $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f_1$, which is not continuous.

Comment: I did not get your explanation.

Comment: OP is saying the $f_i$ must be continuous

Comment: @Nitin Hasn't he

Comment: My comment was directed at @mp100